# OpenGraph post to news feed layout

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I post an action to a Facebook news feed from a website. I am getting a look that is not quite what I want to have:

[image]

I want it to be larger, like this one:

[image]

I am using JS SDK for posting, code comes from App, for testing-only in a dev-env it is currently following: (assuming user is authorized with correct permissions)

```
FB.api(
    'me/aeegens:win',
    'post',
    {
        thropy: "http://samples.ogp.me/444294502324595"
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
};
```

I tried to look for solution in Facebook API documentation, but could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple, one needs to have a bigger image.